# Editstrap - internal js error

Tags: javascript

Using Edistrap, once "tag" type is selected it throws error saying "uncaught type error, tagsInput.tagsinput is not a function". Traced code:

```
var tagsInput = html.find("input");
            tagsInput.tagsinput({
                tagClass : function(item) {
                    return 'label label-info';
                }
            });
            html.removeClass("input-group-sm");
            html.find(".bootstrap-tagsinput").addClass("form-control");
            html.find(".validate").click(function() {
                var allTags = tagsInput.tagsinput('items');
                _this.submitEditable(span, allTags.join(_this.options.multipleSeparator), allTags);
            });
```

I ain't no js programmer so I am asking if this is something I can fix easily.

Comment: You need to provide more information.  Where are you defining a `tagsinput` function?

Comment: This is not my code but source one of Editstrap. Here is entire .js file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xn19cxi2s3pn1lx/editstrap-3.3.1.js?dl=0

Comment: Also, error happens on line 633.

Comment: https://github.com/bootstrap-tagsinput/bootstrap-tagsinput/issues/175

Comment: Dunno, will check if including of that file helps. But this is a whole different repository. Edistrap is located here: https://github.com/MAMABA/editstrap

Comment: Worked like a charm. Can you please post that as an answer so I can mark that as solved? Other users might run into this too.

Comment: I'll decline.  You may answer your own question and get some rep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution by Amy:
Include bootstrap-tagsinput.css & bootstrap-tagsinput.js
from https://github.com/bootstrap-tagsinput/bootstrap-tagsinput/tree/master/src

Note that .css file needs to be edited in terms of colors to work with Editstrap.